# Visual Basic Quicksort Algorithm crash - 'System.StackOverflowException'

Tags: vb.net, algorithm, quicksort

I am currently attempting to code a Quick-sort algorithm in Visual Basic.

I initially attempted this by looking for pre-written code that I can base the algorithm off. However, much of the code that I found was in languages that I have little experience in.

I also attempted this by looking for pseudo code examples. I have compared my code to the pseudo code examples available on the internet but was still unable to get the code running correctly.

The current issue is 'An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in QuickSort.exe' whenever the procedure is ran with any randomly generated data in the 'intGeneratedData' array. This error points to the 'Private Sub' line of the procedure.

```
    Private Sub QuicksortAlgorithm(ByRef intGeneratedData() As Integer, ByVal intSize As Integer)
    Dim intPivotValue, intLower, intUpper, intSwapTemp As Integer

    If (intSize > 1) Then
        intPivotValue = intGeneratedData((Int((intSize * Rnd()) + 1)))
        intLower = 0
        intUpper = (intSize - 1)

        While intLower <= intUpper
            While intGeneratedData(intLower) < intPivotValue
                intLower += 1
            End While

            While intGeneratedData(intUpper) > intPivotValue
                intUpper -= 1
            End While

            'Swap lower and upper value
            If intLower <= intUpper Then
                intSwapTemp = intGeneratedData(intLower)
                intGeneratedData(intLower) = intGeneratedData(intUpper)
                intGeneratedData(intUpper) = intSwapTemp

                intLower += 1
                intUpper -= 1
            End If

        End While

        QuicksortAlgorithm(intGeneratedData, intLower)
        QuicksortAlgorithm(intGeneratedData, (intUpper - intLower))
    End If

End Sub
```

NOTE: When the algorithm is called, 'intSize' is always the size of the array 'intGeneratedData'.

I feel as though there are other errors that I have not mentioned within this procedure as I was previously experiencing another error before I changed multiple things to cause this. I've been trying to get this to work for a few days but without success. Apologies if this thread is uninformative about the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a recursive algorithm and you have no place in the function where you exit it early with a return statement.  You call QuicksortAlgorithm twice more at the bottom of the function.  Your algorithm will never finish - it will just keep calling itself forever.   If I had to guess I'd say to add this to the top of your function:

```
If intSize < 1 Then
   Return
End If
```

From: http://mark.random-article.com/weber/ada/week13.html

See:

Requirements for Recursion

... you are missing an Exit Condition

An Exit Condition or "Stopping Case" (as it is called in the book) -- I have also heard this referred to as a "Base Case". This is the state at which the function will finally return, and not call itself any more. An exit condition is a critical component of a recursive function. If you don't have one in there, it will never exit. **The exit condition will typically be the first thing in your recursive function.**

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I attempted doing this however it is producing the same error at the same location :(

Comment: Hmm.. maybe <= 1... I was trying to do the opposite of your "if" condition

Comment: So "If intSize <= 1 Then"? If so, that isn't working either unfortunately

Comment: Followed the example set on the link, works great. Cheers